# EntityFramework 4.1 ChangeTracker.Entries.Count & SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In EntityFramework 4.1, SaveChanges is not reducing the context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count. Is that normal? Does it have any overhead?

To be clear, say I have to update zip codes for some customers. So, I have the code like below.

```
using (CustomerContext ctx = new CustomerContext())
            {
                var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(a => a.ZipCode = 12345);
                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    customer.ZipCode = 54321;
                    .........
                    ctx.SaveChanges(); //ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count is NOT set to zero
                }
            }
```

I thought in 4.0, ObjectStateManager resets the count to Zero on SaveChanges(), but in 4.1 ChangeTracker.Entries().Count is not. Let me know the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely normal. After saving changes all entities remain attached to the context. Only entities which were deleted during saving changes are detached. The state of modified entries is with default behavior changed from `Modified` / `Added` to `Unchanged`. `ObjectStateManager` behaves absolutely same. `DbChangeTracker` is just build on top of `ObjectStateManager`.